# C++ Not allowing me to pass vector by reference to another function after previously working

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

So I have the following code and it used to work but not it just started giving me an error in Visual Studio.

This is the compiler error I am getting:
c2664 'int partition(int [], int, int, int)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::vector>' to int []'

I have marked the location with "// ERROR HERE".

The odd thing is I randomly started having issues with it not letting me save the file and it was previously running just fine. I believe I copied everything over correctly, if something seems out of place let me know.

Edit1: Added the includes and tested in by itself. It only shows the error I am talking about when I try to compile.

Edit2: It also started randomly insisting that I used unsigned int for my for loop.

Edit3: Condensed version of code. I now see that somehow the prototype for partition got changed.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <new>


//void populateArrayForward(int a[], int n);
void populateArrayForward(std::vector<int>& a);

//void algorithm4(int a[], int n, int k);
int algorithm4(std::vector<int>& a);

int partition(int a[]);

int main()
{   std::vector<int> a;
    a.resize(10);
    // Generate array
    populateArrayForward(a);
    algorithm4(a);
    char b;
    std::cin >> b;
}
int algorithm4(std::vector<int>& a)
{
    int pivotNewIndex = partition(a); // ERROR HERE

}

int partition(std::vector<int>& a)
{

}
```

Comment: I got a bunch of errors trying to compile your code, but not that one.

Comment: @LogicStuff Maybe I messed up on copying it over. I had to cut out a lot. I will check into it.

Comment: @LogicStuff The new code only gives me the error I am talking about.

Comment: There's `int partition(int a[], int left, int right, int pivotIndex);` declaration that does not even match the definition. Should be easy to see if you knew what to look for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line in the function def:

```
int partition(int a[]
```

Would throw an error if partition is expecting a vector:

```
int partition(std::vector<int>& a
```